# Could not connect to DataLab

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I could not connect to datalab of all GCP project.

I tried to connect on several way such as Cloud Shell, local environment, and use another PC, but same issue happened.

Running command to connect succeed, but trying to connect on browser, it is not displayed datalab's home but displayed like below.

[image: error screen from cloud shell]

I entered VM of datalab and checked datalab docker container had been running correctly, the container seemed to be failed to start.

```
$ docker ps -a 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS                      NAMES
bee455ac9f6b        gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab@sha256:913de629df5d90e7a2f85d9b9ec2986adb0f59d8a9e204360d84e770f1147ec8           "/datalab/run.sh"        27 seconds ago      Exited (127) 25 seconds ago                              k8s_datalab_datalab-server-ryutah_default_3335ede982c9f3d4bef6a7f8dcf3948a_0
63a79825ae9e        gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-gcp@sha256:93ae1e71d71c4209947fcc20da66cba7c788ed6fa0b3ebf2b7ca0a32eca39ed4   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/..."   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                                             k8s_logger_datalab-server-ryutah_default_3335ede982c9f3d4bef6a7f8dcf3948a_9
26da06887f72        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0                                                                       "/pause"                 2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                  127.0.0.1:8080->8080/tcp   k8s_POD_datalab-server-ryutah_default_3335ede982c9f3d4bef6a7f8dcf3948a_9
```

That failed docker container output below log.

```
$ docker logs bee455ac9f6b
Verifying that the /tmp directory is writable
The /tmp directory is writable
/ /
From https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at 887cb95 Add a text classification sample with both DNN and LSTM for TensorFlow. (#130)
/
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
/root/startup.sh: line 1: !pip3: command not found
```

Is this the reason why I could not connect to datalab?

This VM has below docker images

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab           latest              43e710d36020        6 weeks ago         2.82 GB
gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64   3.0                 99e59f495ffa        17 months ago       747 kB
gcr.io/google_containers/fluentd-gcp   1.18                e0be8d052951        19 months ago       411 MB
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Please give me answer if someone knows about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this.

The pip install command in startup.sh has `!` lead of the word.

After delete it and restart VM, I can connect to datalab.